# How to constantly update data with Django

Tags: python, django, twitter

I'm building a website with Django (1.7) that pulls tweets from the twitter api.  I would like the latest 10 tweets from a given user. What is the best way to make sure the tweets are up to date?

My idea was to wipe the database of the 10 tweets and grab the newest 10 every 5 minutes?  How would I do this?  Would it be in the model.py file?  Is this the best way to do it?

Right now I have the following code at the bottom of my models.py file.  It populates the data perfectly, but how would I go about updating it?  I'm using twython to interface with the twitter api and python 3.4.

list_of_people are twitter usernames I'm testing with.
twython passes back a list of dicts, I'm then grabbing the data I want from each tweet and putting it in the database

```
twitter = twython.Twython(APP_KEY, APP_SECRET, OAUTH_TOKEN, OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET)

list_of_people = ["billgates", "TheEllenShow"]

for person in list_of_people:
    user_timeline = twitter.get_user_timeline(screen_name=person)
    for x in range(10):
        Category.objects.create(username=person, realname=user_timeline[x]['user']['name'], 
        tweets=user_timeline[x]['text'],tweettime=user_timeline[x]['created_at'])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this in 2 different ways:

- Use cron to call your script periodically. This is the most straightforward and easier solution. No need to configure any extra tools except the cron line.
- Use [celery](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html) to configure a [periodic task](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/userguide/periodic-tasks.html). Definitely, this one will take you more time because you have to learn how to deal with a new (very useful) tool.

If you think you won't need celery for anything else, I would recommend the first one. If you like to learn new things, the second one because the task will be more integrated with Django.

Comment: Thanks so much!  I'll look into these and see which one best suits me and which one I can get working